# Flex Web application Resize method(and Scale X/Y) not working on Server but works on local Flex Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flash

I have a quite different problem with resizing. I have a Flexbook component which uses the middle part of screen (center) with a html header menu and footer.

The problem:
The scaling works perfectly when we run in the local machine ( Flexbuilder). **But when we deploy it to the server its like scaling never existed..**

The requirement:

when user maximizes the window or minimizes it, the Flexbook should be resized to fit the screen.

I've used resize() method of top layer:

```
protected function application1_resizeHandler(event:ResizeEvent):void
{

var scaleX: Number = Application.application.width / 1024;
var scaleY: Number = Application.application.height / 762;

this.scaleX = this.scaleY = (scaleX>scaleY?scaleY:scaleX);

   for (var i:int = 0; i < this.numChildren - 1; ++i) {
if(this.getChildAt(i))
this.getChildAt(i).scaleX = this.getChildAt(i).scaleY = (scaleX>scaleY?scaleY:scaleX);
            }
```

}

Appreciate if anyone can explain why its happening:

1. is there anything needed form server/html side ( parameter/options to enable scaling etc?)
2. can we do something from within Flex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know, nothing is to do on server side. Which browser do you use on developer machine and server?
i would use the remote debugger in flex builder and would check the variables and if anyone calling the method.

BR
Frank

Comment: well in both developer machine and server I tested on IE9 & Chrome.

Comment: the problem is in developer machine with debugger the method running fine. and scaling correctly. I will check with remote debugging :)

Comment: update: I'm having problems getting remote debugger to be working :(

Comment: mybe i can help you if you tell me, which problems you have

Comment: but I tried to connect the debugger but it keeps saying connection timeout. I have already installed the flash player debug edition in IE.